# Move div onclick and back onclick

Tags: jquery, html, click, move

I have a jQuery code that moves a certain div element on right as I click it, i'd like to move it back to its original position when I click back on it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#wel1").click(function() {
        $("#sidemenu").animate({left: "80px"});
    });
});
```

Give me a simple example of how to achieve it?

Comment: There are just too many ways to achieve this.

Comment: Have you removed the even listener that moves the element to the right? If that is still there, clicking again would do nothing as the element is moved both left and right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to achieve it is to store the state in a variable and check its state on click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var sideMenu = false;
    $("#wel1").click(function() {
      if (!sideMenu) {
        $("#sidemenu").animate({left: "80px"});
        sideMenu = true;
      }
      else {
        $("#sidemenu").animate({left: "0px"});
        sideMenu = false;     
      }
    });
});
```

Please be aware that this solution has several issues:

- will not work for multiple menus
- can produce unwanted animation effects ("jumping") if quickly clicked

Comment: You were a little bit faster, basically the same idea, good job ^^

Comment: It is source code and one of its properties is, that it is *changeable*, as simple as using your keyboard and brains.

Comment: I mean, for example: The _#sidemenu_ started at _"0px"_, but he has more than _#wel1_ (as the id suggests it to be number one [and must have more]) he has other elements (_#wel2, #wel3, ..._) that on click changes the left position, it would be a problem always return to _"0px"_ instead of the last left position...

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this by adding an attribute to store the current state of the div.
Implemented at : http://jsfiddle.net/mwtrsw9p/

```
$('#movable').click(function(){
if($(this).attr("trigger")==="0"){
    $(this).animate({"left":"100px"},700);
    $(this).attr("trigger","1");
}
else{
    $(this).animate({"left":"0px"},700);
    $(this).attr("trigger","0");
}
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id = "movable" trigger = "0"></div>
```

CSS :

```
#movable{
position:relative;
height:50px;
width:50px;
background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this way is best:

---

css:

```
.animated_right{
    left:80px;
}
```

---

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#wel1").on("click", function() {
        $("#sidemenu").toggleClass("animated_right", 1000); // 1sec
    });
});
```

---

Comment: jQuery UI extends the jQuery native toggleClass to take duration

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

var toggle = 1;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#wel1").click(function() {
    if (toggle == 1){
        $("#sidemenu").animate({left: "80px"});
toggle = 0;
    } else{
$("#sidemenu").animate({right: "80px"});
toggle = 1;
    }
    });
});
```

You have a variable 'toggle' with a value of 1, when you click it will check if 'toggle' equals 1, if it does it will move to the left, and then set 'toggle' to 0, because of this the first if will result false if you click a second time, and it will use the if statement and move the object to the right, after which it will set the value of 'toggle' to 1 which will result in your desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You need a status to check whether it has been clicked or not, like below:

```
$("#wel1").click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("clicked")){
        $(this).removeClass("clicked");
        $("#sidemenu").animate({left: "80px"});
    }else{
        $(this).addClass("clicked");
        $("#sidemenu").animate({left: "0px"});
    }
});
```

Check out my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1vkuvudz/)..