# Move div from right to left with CSS-transition

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I am working on a drawer where I have to move the div from left to right on button click. I am trying to do this with CSS-transitions and jQuery but it isn't working. Here is my what I tried so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".openUserEditBox").on("click", function() {
    $(".user-drawer").show();
  });
});
```

```css
.user-drawer {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  min-height: 450px;
  float: right;
  display: none;
  left: 100px;
  transition: left 1s ease-in-out;
}

.user-menu {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

.btn-default {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  width: 150px;
}

.btn-default:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px 0 #bbbbbb;
}

.btngroup {
  float: right
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btngroup">
  <button class="btn-default openUserEditBox">Show Drawer</button>
  <button class="btn-default closeUserEditBox">Hide Drawer</button>
</div>
<div class="userForm">
  <div class="user-drawer">
    <div class="user-menu">
      <h1>Edit User</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code in the fiddle is different from what you have here; it doesn't have the `transition` property. In addition, the `show()` function in jQuery changes the `display` property, not the `left` property.

Comment: I have saved the fiddle again and edited the post

Comment: That leaves my other comment, that you're trying to animate the `left` property, but `show()` doesn't change the `left` property, so there's nothing to animate.

Comment: I wanted to display animation on button click. i am able to animate the element on hover. But how do i animate it on click ?

Comment: This can help to solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27843192/move-div-onclick-and-back-onclick

Comment: AKNair - I know to animate using JQuery. Any solution related to only CSS transition  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to transition the `left` property, then you can't use `show()` and `hide()`. Just set the `left` property in the JavaScript.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".openUserEditBox").on("click", function() {
    $(".user-drawer")[0].style.left = '0';
  });
  $(".closeUserEditBox").on("click", function() {
    $(".user-drawer")[0].style.left = '602px';
  });
});
```

```css
.userForm {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.user-drawer {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  min-height: 450px;
  margin-left:auto;
  left: 602px;
  transition:left 1s;
}

.btn-default {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  width: 150px;
}

.btngroup {
  text-align:right;
  margin:8px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btngroup">
  <button class="btn-default openUserEditBox">Show Drawer</button>
  <button class="btn-default closeUserEditBox">Hide Drawer</button>
</div>
<div class="userForm">
  <div class="user-drawer">
    <div class="user-menu">
      <h1>Edit User</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I dispensed with the floats, since they interfered with `overflow` in the user form. Hope it's still useable in its current form.

Comment: translateX better for mobile devices

Comment: @HosMercury In what way?

Answer (score 2):

I just used absolute positioning to to show hide section. And also removed the floating property for section to fix the alignment.

```js
$('.openUserEditBox').click(function() {
    $(".userForm").removeClass("hide");
    $(".userForm").addClass("show");
});
$('.closeUserEditBox').click(function() {
    $(".userForm").removeClass("show");
    $(".userForm").addClass("hide");
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.user-drawer {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    top: 50px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
    min-height: 450px;
}

.user-drawer .active {
    left: 20px;
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

.userForm::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

.user-menu {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: absolute;
}

.btn-default {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
    width: 150px;
}

.btn-default:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px 0 #bbbbbb;
}

.btngroup {
    text-align: right
}

.userForm {
    position: absolute;
    right: -100%;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: 0.6s;
}

.userForm.show {
    visibility: visible;
    right: 0;
}

.userForm.hide {
    visibility: hidden;
    right: -100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btngroup">
    <button class="btn-default openUserEditBox">Show Drawer</button>
    <button class="btn-default closeUserEditBox">Hide Drawer</button>
</div>
<div class="userForm">
    <div class="user-drawer">
        <div class="user-menu">
            <h1>Edit User</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding class and removing that on click and set animation on it

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".openUserEditBox").on("click", function() {
       $(".user-drawer").removeClass("slide-out");
       $(".user-drawer").addClass("slide-in");
  });
  $(".closeUserEditBox").on("click", function() {
       $(".user-drawer").removeClass("slide-in");
       $(".user-drawer").addClass("slide-out");
  });
});
```

```css
.userForm {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.user-drawer {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  min-height: 450px;
  margin-left:auto;
  left: 100%;
}

.btn-default {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  width: 150px;
}

.btngroup {
  text-align:right;
  margin:8px 0;
}

.slide-in {
  animation: slide-in 0.5s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: slide-in 0.5s forwards;
}
.slide-out {
  animation: slide-out 0.5s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: slide-out 0.5s forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide-in {
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes slide-in {
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide-out {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes slide-out {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left:100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btngroup">
  <button class="btn-default openUserEditBox">Show Drawer</button>
  <button class="btn-default closeUserEditBox">Hide Drawer</button>
</div>
<div class="userForm">
  <div class="user-drawer">
    <div class="user-menu">
      <h1>Edit User</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```